# How to run less-rails-bootstrap gem for Bootstrap v2.3.2 in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on upgrading to Rails 4, but I'm not quite ready to upgrade to Bootstrap 3 yet.

Unfortunately, keeping the same version of the `less-rails-bootstrap` gem in my `Gemfile` caused the Glyphicons sprite to fail loading with a 404 error in my staging/production environments.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Rails 4 loads assets from gems differently.

The `less-rails-bootstrap` gem was updated to fix this in [commit cbe20d4593](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap/commit/cbe20d4593e21297f7bc3bc6bc6471a7ad18e890) on GitHub.

To use this particular commit for Bootstrap 2.3.2, I changed the `Gemfile` to instead include this line:

```
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', github: 'metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap', ref: 'cbe20d4593e21297f7bc3bc6bc6471a7ad18e890'
```

Run `bundle install`, and you're golden.